# Why won't my plugs stay put in concrete wall?

Tags: concrete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would plastic anchors pull out of the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/why-would-plastic-anchors-pull-out-of-the-wall)

I have drilled holes in my concrete wall (good hard concrete) with a regular 8 mm concrete drill. They all seem like good holes and I've taken care to remove all remaining dust from the holes by blowing inside with a straw. My 8 mm plugs also go in with just the right amount of friction.

But when I start mounting the cupboard and really want to tighten the last bit, instead of just getting more secure, the plug starts creeping out of the wall! I've tried a couple of different types of concrete plugs, but they all yield the same result.

Is it a good idea to take some kind of filler material and jam it in together with the plug before mounting?

Comment: Your 8mm drill may be makeing a bigger whole then 8mm, so try a smaller drill.   If a drill is bent a little, or you don't hold it 100 still, the whole get be larger then it says.

Comment: See also [why would plastic anchors pull out of the wall?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/why-would-plastic-anchors-pull-out-of-the-wall)

Comment: Excellent answer on the linked question Tester101! Upon examination of my screw length it seems like the problem is that they are too short so the plug never gets a chance to 'bite' properly.

Comment: Well since the answer is really in the other post that Tester101 linked to and that one is almost identical to mine I think this one should probably be marked as duplicate and closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are coming out when you are tightening them, it might be that your hole was not drilled deep enough.  The hole should be at least 1/4" deeper than the screw.

Those plugs also might not be large enough for the job.  Concrete anchor scews (like Tapcon's) are a good alternative when you need more strength then a plug can offer, but don't need a large metal anchor.  On large jobs (like attaching a deck to the house), you can epoxy a bolt in a hole like you suggsted.

Comment: Love the tapcons! I second the motion to give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on scale, you may want to use something like this: **[Socket Anchor](http://www.rawlplug.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=5&Itemid=25)** - you may not be using a plug suitable for concrete.